# pool map no performance gain

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm doing video capture from opencv using the following

```
frame_count = 90000
    while f < frame_count:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        f+=1
        if (f > 41300):
            dst = cv2.warpPerspective(frame.copy(), matrix, (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]))
            pipeline(pool_1, pool_2, frame, car_tracker, ped_tracker, df_region, region_buffered, df_line_car, df_line_ped, det, dst, matrix)
            cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
            cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
```

In function `pipeline`:

```
df_cars= pool_1.map(compute, cars)
df_peds = pool_2.map(compute, peds)
```

`compute` is:

```
def compute(v):
    gb = ('trajectory_id',)
    global general_pd
    id = v[0]
    x = v[1]
    y = v[2]
    frame_id = v[3]
    general_pd.loc[len(general_pd)] = [id, x,y, frame_id]
    grouped = general_pd.loc[general_pd['trajectory_id'] == id]
    df_region = v[4]
    region_buffered = v[5]
    df_line = v[6]
    rpp = RawParameterProcessor(grouped, df_line, frame_idx, df_region, region_buffered,  gb=gb)
    df_parameter_car = rpp.compute()
    return df_parameter_car
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so that I can't get the correct performance gain, I launch two process, and each frame of the video capture I launch a process and do the jobs async, but I don't get any performance gain.

Comment: can you show the type of the pool objects?

Comment: pool_1 = Pool(2)
    pool_2 = Pool(2)

Comment: from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  ```det``` is tensor flow detector, is that the problem ?